# How to edit welcome message in header file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I created following files,

app/design/frontend/Magestore/Sample/composer.json

```
{
"name": "magento/sample-module-theme",
"description": "N/A",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "~100.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0"
},
"type": "magento2-theme",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ]
}
}
```

app/design/frontend/Magestore/Sample/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Magestore/sample',
__DIR__
```

);

app/design/frontend/Magestore/Sample/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Magestore Sample Theme</title>
<parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

app/design/frontend/Magestore/Sample/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

```
<?php
    $welcomeMessage = "Hello";
?>
<?php switch ($block->getShowPart()):
case 'welcome': ?>
    <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
        <span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1'));?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
        <span data-bind="html:'<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php break; ?>

<?php case 'other': ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
<?php break; ?>

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

But changes are not reflected?

Comment: Is that the only file in your theme or is your theme fully set up with registration.php ect also? This theme should also then be enabled within admin.

Comment: @Harri Above files are only there. Module is enabled.

Comment: Did you created your theme?

Comment: @S H Patel I want to modify header file.

Comment: Yes but which theme you are used?

Comment: no, I have not added any theme

Comment: Show your layout file code.

Comment: I have added only above files,  now  I am referring this link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: Which theme are used now?

Comment: Magento/luma is used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60449/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-jassi).

Comment: just remove browser cache and check,

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya - still no effect

Comment: please show your code with full file path.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I have added code

Comment: why have you used default in tempalte path after theme name? you have to remove default folder from path

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I referred this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300720/how-to-override-in-phtml-file-in-magento-2

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya But after removing default in template path still there is no effect

Comment: just update above of your code with path

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya - I have updated above code

Comment: Have you keep space before templates in above path?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya - No I didnot keep any space

Comment: @jassi Now your file path looking correct, just run php bin/magento setup:upgrade, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and clear cache. Also remove var folder and clear browser cache.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya - Still no effect

Comment: @jassi, Have you completed all steps of above, Please check your theme is working or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60499/discussion-between-jassi-and-rakesh-jesadiya).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do but as per your listed file maybe you want to assign header.phtml via a custom module.

By default there no specific file for editing Header. It's all done vai **XML**.

And header container is made in **page_layout** files.

So if you wish to assign a template file for it then you can add following in your module or in your theme default.xml file.

```
<referenceBlock name="header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml">
</referenceBlock>
```

If you have not created any theme then please follow this tutorial: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

And then add that code in your theme default.xml.

Flush cache if enabled and check.

**EDIT :**

Create `app/design/frontend/Magestore/Sample/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml"></referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

If you just want to edit **Default Welcome msg!** as shown in following picture

[image]
Then in backend Go to **Content > Configuration** as shown in following picture

[image]
Click on **Edit** of your applied theme.

[image]
Then simply edit message here

[image]

But if you wish it done it via theme way then Please check my below code

**app/design/frontend/Test/base/theme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Test Base (abstract theme)</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image/>
    </media>
</theme>
```

**app/design/frontend/Test/base/registration.php**

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
        'frontend/Test/base',
        __DIR__
    );
```

**app/design/frontend/Test/base/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "test/theme-frontend-base",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "2.4.0",
    "license": [
        "Proprietary"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**app/design/frontend/Test/base/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header $block
 */
$welcomeMessage = "Woohoo : " . $block->getWelcome();
?>
<?php switch ($block->getShowPart()):
    case 'welcome': ?>
        <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
            <span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1'));?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
            </span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
            <span data-bind="html:'<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </li>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php break; ?>

    <?php case 'other': ?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    <?php break; ?>

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

After all these please execute following commands

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Then after in backend I've selected my theme as following picture
[image]

Then execute following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Just in case in between if you get an permission error then execute following command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Please let me know if you still face any error.
[image]

Comment: can you specify little more

Comment: @jassi : check my updated answer.

Comment: still no effect

Answer (score 3):

You can edit via admin , Follow Below steps to reach out

Content > Configuration > Main Website/Theme > Header > Welcome Text

Comment: you are right. But I wanted to edit using template file.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mix between a module and a theme. Create a theme using this guide as a theme is probably better suited for this purpose:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

You seem like you have done a lot of the files they may just need checking and put within your theme directory and not module.

If you are basing your theme on Magento luma theme replace parent with 'Magento/luma' in theme.xml (as per guide above) Then you can skip the 'Configure Images' and 'Create directories for static files' steps.

Below are examples of main files your are missing from theme and how your files should look. These should be placed within your theme directory 'app/design/frontend/MySpacename/MyTheme'

Registration.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/MySpacename/MyTheme',
__DIR__
);
```

Theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
 <title>MyTheme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
 <parent>Magento/luma</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
 <media>
     <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
 </media>
 </theme>
```

If everthing has gone correctly then you should be able to activate the theme you have created within Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Slect Your Store view -> Change Applied Theme to Myspacetheme.

Flush cache's once you have selected this new theme.